# How to make Apache use PHP 7.3 on server upgraded to Debian 10?

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php, php7

I am upgrading a server from Debian 9 (stretch) to Debian 10 (buster), and am aware (and intend) that this results in PHP being upgraded from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.3.

`php -v` does indeed show that PHP 7.3 is installed, but when trying to login to the web application running on the server, I get a (vague) error message, and, when I create a test page to run `phpinfo`, it shows that Apache still seems to be running PHP 7.0.

I had expected that Apache would switch to using PHP 7.3 as part of the OS upgrade. What do I need to do to make Apache now use PHP 7.3?

Comment: Did your upgrade install `libapache2-mod-php7.3`? Did you enable the apache module?

Comment: I followed the upgrade instructions at https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html
How can tell if `libapache2-mod-php7.3` is installed, and what do I need to do to enable the module?

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep ^i | grep libapache2-mod-php7.3` will show you. If it doesn't return anything, its not installed. `a2enmod` enables apache modules.

Comment: Thank you. It turned out that I had to `a2enmod php7.3` but also `a2dismod php7.0` (and then `systemctl restart apache2`). Feel free to write up as an answer so that I can credit you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper answer from comments:

The upgrade probably did not install the `libapache2-mod-php7.3` package, which is required to integrate `php7.3` into `apache2`.

To check if it is already installed, run

```
dpkg -l | grep ^i | grep libapache2-mod-php7.3
```

If this doesn't return anything, it needs to be installed.

```
apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3
```

Afterwards, disable the old `apache2` module and activate the new:

```
a2dismod php7.0 && a2enmod php7.3 && systemctl restart apache2
```